# add Variable Array to Cookie then getting error

Tags: php, arrays, shopping-cart, setcookie

After input some variable,

PHP code:

```
$CartItem = array(
        'itemID' => $itemID,
        'ProductName' => $ProductName,
        'Option' => $Option,
        'Quantity' => $Quantity,
        'Price' => $Price,
        'Total' => $Total
    );

setcookie('CartItem', $CartItem, null);
```

Output error:

```
Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /Users/user/Sites/app/addtocart.php on line 46
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using cookies for this at all. Instead store the cart in `$_SESSION` and if necessary for long term storage, serialize it to a database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128433/removing-values-from-php-session/8128472#8128472 for some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, cookie data must be in string format.  More importantly, you shouldn't store real data in a cookie, because the user can edit them.

Since you're using PHP, you can utilize sessions... You can use `session_start()` which will set a cookie that you don't need to manage, and then you can set data in the `$_SESSION` variable server-side.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Note that session_start() must be called before anything is output on each page.

Answer (score 0):

We can add one variable at a time in cokkie
so do this

```
$CartItem[] = array(
        'itemID' => $itemID,
        'ProductName' => $ProductName,
        'Option' => $Option,
        'Quantity' => $Quantity,
        'Price' => $Price,
        'Total' => $Total
    );

foreach($CartItem as $key=>$value)
{
setcookie($key, $value, null);

}
```

Comment: ah... Cookie can't support variable array??

Comment: While it may solve the initial issue (or not really, since it will only allow storing one CartItem), the biggger problem is using cookies to store real data (like price and total) which would be user editable.